# SSRS - subtract X amount of days from Start/End date using a parameter's input

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Title might not be worded the greatest.

Anyway, I have a report and I am trying to set a field where a user can enter an amount of days they want subtracted from today's date.

Ex. The report gets data from July 4 to July 4, if they enter 7 in this parameter, it takes the end date and subtracts 7 from it so they get a week's data.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How are you getting your dataset? Is it SQL? it would help if you show how many parameters you have and how you use them? Do you have only one Date parameter? And the user then enters the number of days in another parameter?

Comment: Why not just have two date parameters for the report date range?